# Angular 5 - how to find filename generated by ng build

Tags: angular, laravel

I am building app with laravel and angular 5.

The problem is that `ng build` does not create a **manifest** file which I can read and find out the generated filename to be used in my blade template.

Right now in my blade template I am just reading the **index.html** file generated by `ng build` which I dont like.

In react app I do it easily, in angular app i just want a manifest file generated.

Please help in achieving it or advise suitable method other than reading index.html

Comment: Guys/girls. no one has better method?

Answer (score 0):

As no one replied, i have just started reading the folder and picking filename based on that. It is not the best method but until someone come up and tell me a better way or how to generate manifest file I will have to use this.

I am using `preg_match` to match excluding cache busting hash.

```
if ( $dirHandle = opendir($dirPath) ) {
    while ( ($filename = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false ) {
        list($assetName, ,$assetExtention)  = explode('.', $asset);
        $pattern                            = '/'.$assetName.'\.(\w)+\.bundle\.'.$assetExtention.'/';


        if ( preg_match($pattern, $filename) === 1 ) {
            closedir($dirHandle);
            return url('/').'/apps/'.$assetPath.'/'.$filename;
        }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}
```